# How to format a number with padding in Erlang

Tags: formatting, erlang

I need to pad the output of an integer to a given length.

For example, with a length of 4 digits, the output of the integer 4 is "0004" instead of "4". How can I do this in Erlang?

Answer (score 42):

adding a bit of explanation to Zed's answer:

[Erlang Format specification](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1) is: ~F.P.PadModC.

`"~4..0B~n"` translates to:

```
 ~F. = ~4.  (Field width of 4)
  P. =   .  (no Precision specified)
Pad  =  0   (Pad with zeroes)
Mod  =      (no control sequence Modifier specified)
  C  =  B   (Control sequence B = integer in default base 10)
```

and `~n` is new line.

Comment: You can add explanation to that answer instead of adding another answer. This will help improve that question and help others more.

Comment: @CoralDoe it's not possible to format comments to answers in the way it's done in the explanation answer.

Answer (score 33):

io:format("~4..0B~n", [Num]).

Answer (score 15):

`string:right(integer_to_list(4), 4, $0).`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with [io:format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1) is that if your integer doesn't fit, you get asterisks:

```
> io:format("~4..0B~n", [1234]).
1234
> io:format("~4..0B~n", [12345]).
****
```

The problem with [string:right](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#right-2) is that it throws away the characters that don't fit:

```
> string:right(integer_to_list(1234), 4, $0).
"1234"
> string:right(integer_to_list(12345), 4, $0).
"2345"
```

I haven't found a library module that behaves as I would expect (i.e. print my number even if it doesn't fit into the padding), so I wrote my own formatting function:

```
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc Format an integer with a padding of zeroes
%% @end
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-spec format_with_padding(Number :: integer(),
                          Padding :: integer()) -> iodata().
format_with_padding(Number, Padding) when Number < 0 ->
    [$- | format_with_padding(-Number, Padding - 1)];
format_with_padding(Number, Padding) ->
    NumberStr = integer_to_list(Number),
    ZeroesNeeded = max(Padding - length(NumberStr), 0),
    [lists:duplicate(ZeroesNeeded, $0), NumberStr].
```

(You can use [iolist_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#iolist_to_binary-1) to convert the result to binary, or you can use [lists:flatten](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1)([io_lib:format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2)("~s", [Result])) to convert it to a list.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Eshell V12.0.3  (abort with ^G)
1> F = fun(Max, I)-> case Max - length(integer_to_list(I)) of X when X > 0 -> string:chars($0, X) ++ integer_to_list(I); _ -> I end    end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.43.40011524>
2> F(10, 22).
"0000000022"
3> F(3, 22345).
22345
```