# How can I convert function result?

Tags: erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a number with padding in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251869/how-to-format-a-number-with-padding-in-erlang)

I developed this function :

```
check() ->
  case get_val(Text, H) of
    {ok, {Montant}}       -> io:format("~s", [Montant]);
    {error, pas_echeance} -> io:format("erreur")
  end.
```

this function displayed Montant, this is an example of Montant :45

My goal is to convert this value "45" (which denotes [Tunisian dinars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisian_dinar)) in the "45000" form (so I would have Tunisian millime -- each dinar consist of 1000 millimes).

Comment: currency conversion seems to be good fit for explicit multiplication, tho

Comment: wtf with duplicate? It is beginner question but still - here you add zeros at the end, in the "original" in the front of number.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you convert the value to integer (using list_to_integer("45") or list_to_integer(get_val(Text,H)) and multiply it by 1000.