# In Elixir, how do you format numbers with string interpolation

Tags: elixir

I want to print out a string like

```
IO.puts("Count: #{my_count}")
```

But I want leading zeroes in the output like

```
Count: 006
```

How do I do that and where is that documentation?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`String.pad_leading/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#pad_leading/3)

```
my_count
|> Integer.to_string
|> String.pad_leading(3, "0")
```

Comment: I think it would be more clear to use `String.pad_leading(3, "0")`.

Comment: `rjust` is deprecated

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure there is an integer-to-string with padding formatter method in Elixir. However, you can rely on the Erlang `io` module which is accessible in Elixir with the `:io` atom.

```
iex(1)> :io.format "~3..0B", [6]
006:ok
```

You can find an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251869/how-to-format-a-number-with-padding-in-erlang). I'm quoting it here for convenience:

> `"~3..0B"` translates to:
>
> ```
>  ~F. = ~3.  (Field width of 3)
>   P. =   .  (no Precision specified)
> Pad  =  0   (Pad with zeroes)
> Mod  =      (no control sequence Modifier specified)
>   C  =  B   (Control sequence B = integer in default base 10)
> ```

You can either use it directly, or wrap it in a custom function.

```
iex(5)> :io.format "Count: ~3..0B", [6]
Count: 006:ok
```

Comment: Something that tripped me up was that `:io.format` outputs the formatted string to the group leader and returns `:ok`.  If you need to capture the string before output or are just looking for something like `sprintf`, you want `:io_lib.format`, which will return a binary / Elixir `String.t`

Comment: `io_lib.format` returns a list of chars rather than a binary

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [String.pad_leading/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#pad_leading/3):

```
my_count
|> Integer.to_string
|> String.pad_leading(3, "0")
```

Note that the release note of [v1.3.0](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.3.0) says:

> The confusing String.ljust/3 and String.rjust/3 API has been soft deprecated in favor of String.pad_leading/3 and String.pad_trailing/3

This is a *soft deprecation*. Its use does not emit warnings.